# Where's the most appropriate place to normalize data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using the JSON API Spec along with the [json-api-normalizer package](https://github.com/yury-dymov/json-api-normalizer). I'm running into a dilemma when it comes to normalizing single objects with included associations. For instance: I have a single restaurant that has many menus. The only time this becomes a hinderance is when the data is normalized and I need to retrieve the single restaurant that is now nested and can only be retrieved by knowing it's key, which in this case is it's id. This leads me to ask whether I'm normalizing my data in the wrong place. Right now I'm doing it in my reducer on successful retrieval:

```
case types.FETCH_RESTAURANT_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    data: normalize(action.payload, { camelizeKeys: false }),
    error: null, loading: false,
  };
```

Where and what would be the best way to normalize my data so that I'm not essentially locked out of getting the things I need? Here is the output of the normalized state:

```
{
  restaurant: {
    data: {
      restaurant: {
        123: {...}
      },
      menus: {
        345: {...},
        678: {...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this is only an issue when the data are getting really HUGE, otherwise you could normalize them in where you feel easy to maintain for your own favor. But if it's getting big, I think you need to design it with some lazy loading and consider with your business rules. Only render and normalize when needed.